# 2D interpolation using TriScatteredInterp (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Let us consider I have a set of points, which are described as a pair of 2D coordinates. At every single point, I have the value of a given parameter, let us say, temperature.

> Point 1 : `(x1, y1, t1)`
>
> Point 2 : `(x2, y2, t2)`
>
> ...
>
> Point n : `(xn, yn,tn)`

All those points are contained within a 2D domain which is shaped as a triangle.

I would like to interpolate parameter t within the extend of the entire domain. Any interpolation method (linear, nearest neighbors,...) would be fine, to me. I am deeply convinced I achieve this using MATLAB - more precisely using [`TriScatteredInterp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterp.html). However, it does not seem to work. It fails to create the interpolant.

Here is what I have tried so far :

```
x = [0, 1, 1, 0]
y = [0, 0, 1, 1]
t = [10, 20, 30, 20]
F = TriScatteredInterp(x, y, t)
```

The last line yields the following error :

> ??? Error using ==> `TriScatteredInterp`
>
> Input data must be specified in column-vector format.

It seems the way I have given the input is wrong. I have made some research over Google, though I couldn't find the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear... it says the data must be in column vectors.  You have them as row vectors.  Simply put, transpose your data before calling the function:

```
>> F = TriScatteredInterp(x.', y.', t.')

F = 

  TriScatteredInterp with properties:

         X: [4x2 double]
         V: [4x1 double]
    Method: 'linear'
```

FWIW, if you read the documentation, you would see that column vectors are required: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterp.html

---

Once you create your interpolant, you can use any `(x,y)` coordinates of any size to be used in the interpolant, and the result will give interpolated values that match the size of both `x` and `y`... so something like this could work:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(min(x),max(x)), linspace(min(y),max(y)));
out = F(X,Y);
```

The output will be a grid of `(x,y)` coordinates that was applied to the interpolant... basically, you would get an interpolated surface using `X` and `Y` as unique `(x,y)` pairs.

Comment: @RolandY. - Glad it did!  Good luck!