# Interpolating Missing Frames in Matlab

Tags: matlab, frame, interpolation

I am interested in "repairing" a "damaged" frame by interpolating between the former and next frame (Thus, ignoring the bad frame and creating a new one without the damage).

I could try:

```
 c = ((1-r)*a + r*b); %Where r = 0.5
```

And it creates an intermediate frame as desired, however it introduces blur to the image which I would like to avoid. If I remove the r factor (essentially equating it to 1), the resulting frame is basically the latter frame in the equation (in this case b), so it isn't exactly the intermediate image I would like to achieve. Q1: How may I obtain an intermediate, non-blurred image?

I am aware of the scatteredInterpolant function in Matlab, but I'm not sure how to implement it. I've seen a similar question: [2D interpolation using TriScatteredInterp (Matlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174626/2d-interpolation-using-triscatteredinterp-matlab)

However,

```
t = [10, 20, 30, 20]
F = TriScatteredInterp(x, y, t)
```

the use and need of t confuses me. I am thinking x and y can be the pixel locations of the former and next frames respectively (So I would need to run this function in a loop that runs through each pixel), but I have a feeling I may be looking at this function wrong. Q2: Can this function be used to achieve an intermediate,non-blurred image and how may I do so if yes?

Comment: [Motion interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_interpolation) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Well after looking for a matlab implementation of that, I found http://scholar.harvard.edu/stanleychan/software/subpixel-motion-estimation-without-interpolation. (in case anyone else is curious). Not sure if it's actually the intermediate it's finding though. Still trying to understand it. Do you know of another Matlab implementation of motion interpolation, though @Daniel ?

Comment: Never did any research on that topic in connection with MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Its no interpolation , but maybe the median function can help you. If B is your corupted pixel and A is the pixel in the Frame before and C in the Frame after that, your final pixel is B=median[A,B,C]. This works for no motion. But with motion you need a function to interpolate the pixels. My Guess